# SQL injection attack from localhost on live server

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

This is quite complex to explain but I keep getting injection attacks from another website by just clicking on a link. Oddly though it seems Google Chrome is the one generates it.

To elaborate, I have this site: http://byassociationonly.com and I have this site: http://dev.byassociationonly.com/example (can't name site as its a client site).

Whenever I click on any of the links on http://byassociationonly.com, in Google Chrome, on my machine, none of them work and I get an injection attack (I am using a plugin to send me email notifications when something like this happens, Wordpress Firewall).

The notification I receive is this: http://cl.ly/image/2U111T0m2X35

I just don't understand this error at all, Ive never had a problem before.

I've even removed the code within that page its referencing, which is from single.php, yet the problem still exists. I thought there were conflicts with my MAMP servers running locally but even if they are switched off, the problem still exists but localhost:8888 isn't referenced at all within wp_config.

However if I do this within Firefox, I don't get any notifications at all and the links work fine.

Has anybody got any ideas how to identify where the problem lies and solutions to fix?

As requested here's the code on the single.php page, that the error is reffering to: http://pastebin.com/QKqtLXQi

Comment: Ask on the Wordpress Firewall support forum, they may help you more efficiently.

Comment: What type of content do you have on that page? Are you inadvertently generating a dynamic query in a way that may be causing the engine to think its SQL Injection attack? Can you share what type of dynamic SQL (if any) you have on the landing page?

Comment: Please see amended code above

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently install any Chrome extension? I have run into a similar problem before and after hours of troubleshooting it turned out to be an extension blocking some stuff. The fact that it works fine in FF, it feels like an isolated issue.

Comment: Its funny, I did disable all extensions on the off chance it might work but I still had issues. Thanks though.

Comment: Interesting....did you try inspecting the offending link(s) in Chrome? I still think there's something in your Chrome that's causing this. I downloaded the Wordpress Firewall plugin and looked at the code and didn't find anything unusual there. I also tried clicking some links on your website and they all worked for me (in Chrome, I mean).

Comment: Well I've used dev tools and turned wp_debug on but no errors are displayed on that localhost page. Thanks for taking a look at the plugin. Do you think my functions.php code could cause any of these problems: http://pastebin.com/r7Xe4bwu ??

Comment: No, I don't see anything wrong in your functions.php either. When you were inspecting the links, did you by any chance see any extra URL params attached to them by Chrome?